# Problem in learning Blender

Tags: modeling

I am not new in blender, I have known it since 2014. But I never learnt it seriously. Every time when I go through the basic intro videos and some youtube videos I feel like i am doing ok, but when i open up blender and try to create something I can't. As a result, i get frustrated and i quit learning. Now it is 2017 and i haven't learnt a thing. So, if anyone can suggest some effective methods of learning and how to control my frustration please reply.

Thank you.

[P.S] - I am a school student and can't dedicate all my concentration to it.

Comment: Well, this may be opinion based, but the first though I'd say is "start small" (try to imagine how many simple but concrete things can be done with simple cubes or their variations and using surrounding technics like modifiers, for instance). Learn the necessity of quads, in particular in Blender. Use tutorials, but use them not to just copy/mimic them but to understand what is done and how. Be patient, don't hesitate to redo things if you understand you are in the wrong way. Keep geometry simple and learn topology (google "3D topology" you'll see many things). Advice, but, opinion based...

Comment: Your strategy of getting frustrated and quitting is not going to get you very far (not only with blender). There is so much pleasure in working through a problem until it is no longer a problem. The best way to learn is by getting pleasure or some satisfaction from doing it. Work on that and you'll learn not only about blender but life itself. Don't give up.

Comment: As lemon says, start small. Set yourself small challenges that are achievable in a short timescale and concentrate on that until your satisfied with the result. For ideas, use this site - pick a problem that someone else is having that interests you and is close to your current skill level. Investigate it and research it and then write up an answer and submit it. This way you'll have to push yourself to make sure you fully understand it before you move on. You can be sure you understand it if you can successfully explain it to someone else. Small steps and don't give up! Good luck.